# Converting tuples

Tags: haskell, tuples, list-comprehension

I want to write a functions which takes the input parameter xs, which represents a list of tuples of the form (a,b,cs) and convert it to a list of tuples (a*b,b+c), for a and b representing whole numbers and all elements c in cs with cs representing a list of numbers.

The result should only include tuples in which the first element of the tuple is bigger but not even than its second element.

Example:

```
  [(13,25,[1,12,101]), (5,6,[7,17,27])]

  -- should be converted to 

  [(325,26),(325,37),(325,126),(30,13)]
```

Update: After a lot of testing i found this solution but I am not quite sure  how to remove the tuples which do not match the requirements from the resulting list:

```
  convert :: [(Int, Int, [Int])] -> [(Int, Int)]
  convert xs = [(a*b,b+c) | (a,b,cs) <- xs, c <- cs]
```

Comment: Can you show what you should do if the third element is an singleton list?

Comment: Singleton lists should not be valid inputs here.

Comment: So `[(14,25, [3])]` is invalid?

Comment: Yes it should be. The third element should always be a list with 3 elements.

Comment: then it makes no sense to use a list, if something has a fixed number of elements, it is better to use a tuple, since that gives stronger guarantees.

Comment: Nevermind the third element should contain 3 or more elements, but not less than 3.

Comment: Can you at least show *some* effort in solving the problem for a very limited subset of input?

Comment: Hints: Try a nested list comprehension, one for the outer list and one for the list in each tuple, and `concat` to glue them back into one output list. You can also easily find out how to filter the output with list comprehension, any tutorial should cover it.

Comment: Consider `newtype ThreePlus a = ThreePlus a a a [a]` as a way to represent a "list" of three or more `a`s.

Comment: Why is `(30,23)` not in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to iterate further on the third element. We furthermore should add a *filter* a boolean expression in the "body" of the list-comprehension that is checked such that only items satisfying this condition are added:

```
convert xs :: (Num a, Ord a) => [(a, a, a)] -> [(a, a, a)]
convert xs = [ (a*b,b+c) | (a, b, cs) <- xs, c <- cs, a*b > b+c ]
```

we thus unpack the tuples in the original list `xs`, and then use `cs` (the third item of the tuple) as the source of the second generator.

For example:

```
Prelude> convert [(13,25,[1,12,101]), (5,6,[7,17,27])]
[(325,26),(325,37),(325,126),(30,13),(30,23)]
```

Or we can use [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) instead:

```
convert xs :: (Num a, Ord a) => [(a, a, a)] -> [(a, a, a)]
convert xs = filter (uncurry (>)) [ (a*b,b+c) | (a, b, cs) <- xs, c <- cs ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the output list of this exercise has a mistake in it. You are right (30,23) has to be included in the resulting list.